# How do I refine my code in Sikuli? Seems very long and redundant

Tags: python

I'm only just beginning in programming.

The goal of the program is to check to make sure images are properly rendered within a program(within a VM)

. Below is the code, and I am asking what I can do to clean it up.

I don't think you can tell much without the .png's, but I would appreciate it if anyone knows where/how I can optimize my code.

Thank you very much for any help,

```
var=(0) #Empty Variable
jpgl=0 #NUMBER PASSES
vm = App("C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\\vmware.exe")
switchApp("vm")
reg=( )
reg.find( )
#------------------------------------
#BEGINNING SPECIAL CASES/NAVIGATION
if not exists( ):
    switchApp("vm")
    type(Key.BACKSPACE)
    onAppear( ,type(Key.BACKSPACE))
if exists( ):
    click( )
#if exists( ):#attempt to get rid of.
#   click( )
else:
    exists( )
    click( )
    exists( )
    click( )
    wait(1)
    if not exists ( ):#if the image hasn't already loaded, wait the maximum 5 seconds
        wait(5)
#END FOLDER NAVIGATION
#----------------------------------
#BEGIN IMAGE CHECK 1
    if not exists ( ):
        print("B-JPEG_L-20.jpg not displayed correctly")
    if exists( ):
        print("B-JPEG_L-20.jpg Unable to play")
        click( )
    else:
        jpgl=jpgl+1#if the image exists, it moves on by clicking "next"
        click( )
        wait(1)
        if not exists ( ):
            wait(5)
#DONE IMAGE CHECK 1
#----------------------------------
#BEGIN IMAGE CHECK 2
.....

#end code
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to get started improving your script is to find repeated code, then create a function to hold it.

For example, if your code starting with #BEGIN IMAGE CHECK 1 is duplicated for subsequent image checks, it could become a function that takes a Sikuli image file name - define it somewhere near the top of your file (NOTE: This assumes the same image filename is used consistently across this entire chunk of code, which may not be true in your unedited code):

```
def check_image(image_filename):
        if not exists(image_filename):
                print("%s not displayed correctly" % image_filename)
        if exists(image_filename):
                print("%s Unable to play" % image_filename)
                click(image_filename)
        else:                  
                jpgl = jpgl + 1                                                 
                click(image_filename)
                wait(1)        
                if not exists (image_filename):
                        wait(5)
```

Then below that you can call the function with:

```
check_image('foo.jpg')
```

Then you should have a starting point for incrementally refining your code. At some point creating a class to hold your test logic could be useful as well.

I recommend reading up on functions and classes in Python - solid knowledge in those areas really helps out with Sikuli development:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#tut-classes